# How can I tell the validity area of an RMV Tageskarte?

Tags: germany, buses

I need to travel between multiple locations using [RMV](https://www.rmv.de), with three stops in total before I get back home.  Most likely, a *Tageskarte* (day pass) is the most economical option, as I otherwise rarely travel by local public transportation.  However, I'm not sure what pass to buy and what the validity is.

I found a [map](https://www.rmv.de/c/fileadmin/documents/PDFs/_RMV_DE/Fahrkarten/Regeln/Tarifgesamtplan.pdf) with zones, where there are A-Zones and smaller A0-zones.  My stops are in A0-zones 3550, 3601, 3525, and 3501, which corresponds to A-zones 3500 and 3600.  When I search (for example) Offenbach (3601) via Langen (3501) to Dietzenbach (3550), the [planner](https://www.rmv.de/) indicates no price except for trips that take a detour via Frankfurt (A0-zone 5010, A-zone 5000, special conditions at higher price).  I seem to recall having heard from a bus driver that a *Tageskarte* in particular is valid within the full A-zones it passes through (I think he actually said the entire Landkreis, which is two A-zones), which would mean that a *Tageskarte* from 3601 to 3501 would also be valid to continue to 3550.  However, I cannot find such a rule in the [conditions](https://www.rmv.de/c/de/fahrkarten/infos-regeln/befoerderungsbedingungen-tarifbestimmungen/tarifbestimmungen), nor can I find confirmation using the [planner](https://www.rmv.de/).

In the [conditions](https://www.rmv.de/c/de/fahrkarten/infos-regeln/befoerderungsbedingungen-tarifbestimmungen/tarifbestimmungen) I have found that *Werden in zwei A-Tarifgebieten vier und mehr A0-Tarifgebiete befahren, gilt Preisstufe 4.*, which means *are in two A-zones four or more A0-zones covered, price class 4 applies*.  Including A0-zones I'm just transiting, I have five or six A0-zones; maybe that means that since my ticket already covers four A0-zones within two A-zones (I think they mean ≥4 A0-zones in total, rather than ≥4 A0-zones within each A-zone), that validity to the fifth one (within the same A-zone) is implied, i.e., if I cover at least 4 A0-zones within 2 A-zones, I can travel within the entirety of the A-zones — more or less consistent with what I seem to recall having heard from the bus driver?  Would this interpretation be correct?  I'm not sure if this paragraph about single tickets also applies to day passes.

Is a day pass from 3601 to 3501 (which transits 3525 and either 3510 or 3680) valid for travel to 3550?  How can I tell?  Or how would I find the most suitable day pass that's valid for travel in 3601, 3510, 3680, 3525, 3501, and 3550 — if such a day pass exists?

*Long live the simplicity of local transportation in Germany!*

Comment: This is indeed complicated. I think you need to work out what the **Preisstufe** is for a single journey that passes through all AO zones and buy the Tageskarte for that Preisstufe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RMV website has an option to indicate the zones in which the day pass is valid.  To get this information, search for a specific connection, click on the `>` the open connection details, then click on *Tarif*, then on *Tageskarten*, and then on the `>` next to the type of *Tageskarte* under consideration.  A ticket from the Frankfurter Straße in Offenbach to the Frankfurter Straße in Langen (direct route) is valid in tariff zones 3500, 3600, 5000, 5090, 2645, 4089, 6649, and 6664:

[image: Screenshot RMV.de]

One can then also click on *Freigegebene Städte/Gemeinden* for more information, including a full list of municipalities and cities where it is valid:

[image: Another screenshot]

The conclusion in this specific case is that a *Tageskarte* with *Preisstufe* 4 is indeed valid in the entire A-areas 3500 and 3600, including Offenbach, Dreieich (of which Sprendlingen is a part), Langen, Dietzenbach, and even all the way to Seligenstadt and Frankfurt including the airport.  However, if one searches only to the far north of Langen, then the Tageskarte is **not** valid in the entire A-Zone, because it is only *Preisstufe* 3:

[image: Another RMV.de screenshot]

In this case, 3550 is *not* listed.  For the journey described in the question, one has the choice:

- A *Tageskarte* with *Preisstufe 4* for €11.30, valid with continuation to Dietzenbach, or
- A *Tageskarte* with *Preisstufe 3* for €7.40 and a single ticket onward to Dietzenbach (also *Preisstufe 3*) for €3.80, totalling €11.20, or some other combination of a single ticket and a *Tageskarte*.